# show loading-spinner until google-map is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, google-maps, lazy-loading

I'm using the jQuery Lazy Load XT plugin to lazy load my google-map iframe data-src.

It works fine.

Demo here: http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/widget-iframe.htm

But I need to add a spinner to it while the map is loading.
And you can easily do that by including the spinner css-file to the site: https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt/#spinner

But the problem is: When the map starts loading, the spinner shows up, and then goes away while the map is loading.

So, how can I show the spinner until the map is FULLY loaded?
I don't want the spinner to show for 2 seconds, then disapear, and the see a empty iFrame until the map is FULLY loaded.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. You don't have scripting-access to the document inside the iframe, the only event that may be observed is the load-event of the iframe(which will fire before the map has been loaded)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thank's for your answer! Do you know any other possible solutions for this problem?

Comment: create your own map by using the maps-javascript-API and observe the `tilesloaded`-event of the map to hide the spinner

Comment: a simple implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/p9ej9bzu/

Comment: @Dr.Molle Your implementation loads the googleMap when the rest of the site is finished loading, right? How can I load the map only when I scroll to the specific div that it's loaded in?

Comment: You're right. See my answer for a  implementation of spinner & lazy-loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jQuery-plugin that implements the spinner & lazy-loading for maps:

```
(function( $ ){

 $.fn.lazyMapLoad = function(opts) {
    var defaults={
                  center:{lat:0,lng:0},
                  zoom:1,
                  //style used to show the spinner
                  'style':{background:"url('http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/dist/loading.gif') center center no-repeat" }

                 },
      maps=this;

    //callback for API-load
    window.lazyMapLoadInit=function(){

      $.each($.unique($('head').data('maps')),function(i,o){
        $(o).trigger('lazyMapLoad.load');
      });
      delete window.lazyMapLoadInit;
    };

    maps.each(function() {
      var that=$(this),
        //collect properties for Maps-instance
        props=$.extend({},defaults,opts,that.data('map'));

        //create map-container
        that.empty().css(props.style).append($('<div></div>').css({height:'100%',opacity:0}))

        //when the map should be loaded
        that.on('lazyMapLoad.load',function(){

            //API not available yet, push the map to the stack
            if(!window.google || !window.google.maps || !window.google.maps.Map){
              var maps=$('head').data('maps')||[];
              maps.push(this);
              $('head').data('maps',$.unique(maps))
            } 

            //load the API
            if(!window.google || !window.google.maps){             
              window.google={maps:{}};
              $('<script/>',
                {src:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=lazyMapLoadInit'})
                .appendTo('head');
            }
            //API available, load the map
            if(window.google && window.google.maps && window.google.maps.Map){
             that.off('lazyMapLoad.load');
             var data=that.data('map')||{};
                 data.map=new google.maps.Map(this.firstChild,props);
                 that.data('map',data);
                 google.maps.event.addListener(data.map,'tilesloaded',function(){
                  $(this.getDiv()).animate({opacity:1});
                 });
            }
        });
  });

  //observe scroll
  $(window).on('scroll',function (){
      //no maps to proceed
      if(!maps.length)return;

      var _maps=maps,
          offset=$(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height();

      //compare the position of each map
      maps.each(function(i,o){
        if(offset>=$(o).offset().top){
          $(o).trigger('lazyMapLoad.load');
          _maps=_maps.not(o);
        }
      });

      maps=_maps;

  }).trigger('scroll');

  return this;
}
} ( jQuery ));
```

Usage:

```
$('selector').lazyMapLoad();
```

The options for the google.maps.Map-instance will be derived from:

1. the default settings  `{center:{lat:0,lng:0},zoom:1}`
2. the options passed as argument when calling the plugin
3. the `data-map`-attribute of the particular elements

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/bj6u0ncj/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/bj6u0ncj/)